# Объект стоящий на крутящемся цилиндре не крутится

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть цилиндр с размерами 2,0.3,2. Он крутится со случайной скоростью в случайном направлении.
На нем есть MeshCollider.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        cylinder.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
    }
```

На него сверху с небольшой высоты падает капсула. Падает она засчет Rigidbody.
Ну и цилиндр крутится, а стоящая на нем капсула, не крутится, как будто стоит в воздухе, хотя она на нем.

Comment: Сделай кручение цилиндра с помощью физики RigidBody

Comment: Не могу разобраться как сделать такое кручение, с разной скоростью и направлением, это возможно?

Comment: возможнно______________

Answer (score 0):

А с чего он должен крутиться?

> Представьте себя на месте капсулы: она упала, под ней объект, он спокойно стоит, *не крутясь*, так как вращение осуществляется не с помощью физики rigibody. Так с чего же капсуле крутится, если на ее rigidbody ничего не взаимодействует.

Заставить ее крутиться можно 2 способами:

- Сделать ее дочерней по отношению к цилиндру - плохой способ, так как вращение будет нереалистичным
- Вращать цилиндр с помощью [Rigidbody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html), который и является физическим вращением объекта.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, но все же одна вещь мне непонятна, если я бросаю сверху на этот цилиндр кубик, то он вращается вместе с цилиндром, но если я бросаю на этот цилиндр капсулу, то она стоит как ни в чем не бывало, и не крутится, не знаете из-за чего такое происходит?

Comment: А как вы крутите ваш кубик? Я в тестовом проекте создал кубик, к нему прикрепил код,скопированный с RIgidbody.MoveRotation (ссылка в ответе), от крутится, цилиндр на нем крутится. Проверьте, что у вас и на цилиндре и на кубике rigidbody вообще есть.

Comment: Нет, у меня есть цилиндр с размерами 2,0.3,2 ( короче говоря таблетка ). Она крутится засчет RigidBody, на нее сверху падает кубик, на котором висит Rigidbody. Кубик крутится, все отлично. Но если заменить кубик на капсулу, стандартных размеров, то капсула приземляясь на таблетку, не крутится совершенно.

Comment: А капсула падает вертикально? То есть гранями вверх и вниз? По-моему она и не будет крутиться, это будет незаметно (да и координаты поворота вроде не будут меняться). А если бросить ее под наклоном, то она упадет и будет крутиться. В любом случая, если я все же не понимаю описываемого вами события, предлагаю вам добавить скриншот или видео в вопрос именно с цилиндром на кубике.

Comment: Вопроса о цилиндре на кубике и не было, только наоборот. Крутится цилиндр, а на него сверху уже падают разные фигуры. Например кубик, который находится на цилиндре, крутится, капсула расположенная гранями вверх и вниз не крутится, вытянутый цилиндр с таким же расположением граней тоже не крутится, собственно вопрос в том, почему кубик крутится, и координаты поворота у него меняются, а другая фигура при абсолютно тех же условиях не крутится, и координаты поворота не меняет

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zG8r5fc

Comment: Что же, тогда не знаю, чем вам помочь. У меня код из документации, ссылку на которую я скинул работает абсолютно корректно, вне зависимости ни от чего. Честно, не могу сказать, что не так у вас:(

Comment: Создал пустой проект, создал Plane на котором будет цилиндр,создал цилиндр (2,0.3,2) , добавил ему RigidBody, до единой буквы скопировал скрипт из документации по MoveRotation, накинул этот скрипт на цилиндр. Цилиндр вращается. Создал кубик над цилиндром, добавил ему Rigidbody. Запускаю сцену, кубик падает на вращающийся цилиндр, и не вращается. То же самое происходит с капсулой и другим цилиндром. Убрал Plane на котором лежит вращающийся цилиндр, и включил у цилиндра "Is Kinematic". Теперь цилиндр вращается в воздухе, падающий на него кубик теперь вращается тоже. Но другие фигуры увы,нет.

Comment: А какой коллайдер вы используете?, просто по стандарту на цилиндре висит Capsule Collider,он не совсем по форме цилиндра, и отталкивает все что на него падает, по этому я использую Mesh Collider

Comment: Работает у меня c любым коллайдером. IsKinematic на true значит, что на объект не действуют никакие физические силы, он под полным контролем анимации и скриптов. У меня все работает как раз С IsKinematic